# Error when installing "python-nautilus"

Tags: 11.10, python

When I try to install `python-nautilus` using the Ubuntu Software Center I get an error message titled "Package dependencies cannot be resolved".

The following output is displayed in the details section:

```
Package dependencies cannot be resolved

The following packages have unmet dependencies:

python-nautilus: Depends: libc6 (>= 2.2.5) but 2.13-20ubuntu5 is to be installed
             Depends: libglib2.0-0 (>= 2.16.0) but 2.30.2-4ubuntu1~oneiric1 is to be installed
             Depends: libgtk-3-0 (>= 3.0.0) but 3.2.0-0ubuntu3 is to be installed
             Depends: libnautilus-extension1 (>= 1:2.91) but 1:3.2.1-0ubuntu3.2 is to be installed
             Depends: libpython2.7 (>= 2.7) but 2.7.2-5ubuntu1 is to be installed
```

This output doesn't make sense for me. Depends on `libpyhon2.7`, and version `2.7.2` is available... What is going wrong here?

Next, I tried to install `python-nautilus` from command line:

```
username ~$ sudo apt-get install python-nautilus
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 python-nautilus : Depends: python-gobject but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

However, `python-gobject` is already installed:

```
username ~$ sudo apt-get install python-gobject
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
python-gobject is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

To me it looks like my package index must be hopelessly broken. However, I did not have any problems with other packages, yet. I am using a nearly fresh Version 11.10 of Ubuntu. I tried executing `apt-get update && apt-get upgrade`` but this doesn't change anything.

Any hints how I can fix this issue are appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your error messages are probably related to the fact that you have [Gnome-3 PPA](https://launchpad.net/~gnome3-team/+archive/gnome3) enabled.

A recent change in this PPA promoted the use of python-gobject and deprecated the use of python-nautilus.

Basically you can't have python-nautilus installed.

You have a couple of choices:

1. Stick with using the PPA and you cannot continue using nautilus-actions etc.
2. `ppa-purge` the Gnome-3 PPA and you will then be able to use nautilus-actions etc.

You should perhaps post a bug-report on the Gnome-3 PPA to see if they have any thoughts on backporting nautilus-actions from Precise to Oneiric.

Comment: The version of nautilus-actions available in oneiric is non-functional, wasn't rebuilt for gtk3 till precise. *the  3.1.4 or 3.1.5 source can be self built on oneiric

Comment: Wow, I impressed that you found out that I have Gnome3 PPA enabled! After ``ppa-purge`` I could install python-nautilus without problems. Thank you!